# Facebook custom button login will not give me a token

Tags: facebook, swift2, ios9, fbsdk

i am trying to get AccessToken from Facebook and use it with alamofire to login into app.
When I run the app it will crash because currentAccessToken is nil.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
private func getFBUserData(){

    if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){

        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "name, email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                //user and mail
                print(result["email"], result["name"])

                // var myToken = FB
                let currentToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().hashValue
                print(currentToken)

                self.postRequests.loginUserFB(String(currentToken)) {(done) in
                    //completion handler
                    print("login \(done)")

                }
            }
        })
    }
```

}

Comment: Anyone will help me with this topic? I want Custom Facebook login button.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using default facebook login view provided by FB sdk, use delegate method of FBSDKLoginButton and get the access token as-

```
- (void)  loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result
            error:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"acessToken:%@ ,user Id : %@",[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken],result.token.userID);
NSLog(@"error : %@",error);
}
```

for custom you can use

```
var fbAccessToken = FBSession.activeSession().accessTokenData.accessToken
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But i need swift code + FBSession don't work.
 `Use of unresolved identifier 'FBSession'`

Comment: anyone will help? :-)

Comment: FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() check out this link if you are doing anything wrong.
http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-use-login-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-for-swift/